# SSIS: Me podrian ayudar a saber como se Inserta en un campo excel un parametro input de integration service

Tags: sql, ssis

[image: En los cuadros rojos quisiera poner la fecha de incio y de fin, estos datos son los parametros que uso para consultar y hacer la exportación en Excel]

En los cuadros rojos quisiera poner la fecha de incio y de fin, estos datos son los parametros que uso para consultar y hacer la exportación en Excel

En los cuadros rojos quisiera poner la fecha de incio y de fin, estos datos son los parametros que uso para consultar y hacer la exportación en Excel